how to save/restore/reload stamp annotations , pdf.js / mozilla lib
how to save/restore/reload stamp annotations from my database ..
I need to save STAMP_ANNOTATIONS and in Database and reload it when reOpen the the document and and render it will show ..
how to handle that ? in best way and use exist apis .. is need to add another switch case in updateParams function ?
note , i built my app in vue js then add library files to my project to use it ..
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js
i tried to call updateParams but this.#editorTypes is null .. there is annotation_edit_params,annotation_edit_layer,annotation_layer.js , tools.js , pdf_viewer.js
how to save/restore/reload stamp annotations from database and save in database..
